# Change a key from a number to a string using to_xml in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If you have a hash:

```
{"0" => "value"}
```

And you turn it into XML:

```
{"0" => "value"}.to_xml
```

that returns:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<hash>
  <0>value</0>
</hash>
```

This causes Chrome and many other XML parsers to choke, because the nodename is an integer. Does anyone have a clever / simple solution to fix this? I'm using `respond_with` and a hash, so extra points if I don't have to break that convention in my controller.

Comment: why do you forced to generate a xml with integers as values?

Comment: It's coming from an API (facebook) over which I have no control.

Comment: but which kind of xml you wish to get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to change the key/nodename to a non-numeric string to make it a valid XML element.

Assuming you can prefix the nodename with "Digit":

```
new_hash = {}
hash.each do  |k, v| 
  new_hash.merge!( k.gsub(/^\d/, "Digit#{k[0]}" ) => v ) 
end

new_hash.to_xml
```

[See this for more details on xml nodes with integer names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10398358/access-xml-nodes-with-integer-names)

Comment: Seems like the regex is the way to go. I'll probably just do that in the generated xml since it'll be simpler that way, and create a new action specifically to do this. Thanks!