# JAXWS SOAPHandler for filtering out the Invalid xml chracters

Tags: java, jax-ws

I have a webservice where in a client passes a string with some invalid xml characters. And while parsing the request on the server side the JAXWS throws exceptions because it cannot parse the invalid xml characters.

So as to solve this issue I try to create the following SOAPHandler. In the SOAPHandler below I try to iterate the child elements which means i am already parsing the xml and hence get the exception in the handler itself.

How can i remove the invalid xml characters from the message?

```
import java.util.Set;

import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPBodyElement;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPException;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPMessage;
import javax.xml.ws.handler.MessageContext;
import javax.xml.ws.handler.soap.SOAPHandler;
import javax.xml.ws.handler.soap.SOAPMessageContext;

import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class InvalidXmlCharacterHandler implements SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext>{

     private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(InvalidXmlCharacterHandler.class);


    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext context) {

        System.out.println("Server : handleMessage()......");

        Boolean isRequest = (Boolean) context.get(MessageContext.MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY);

        //for request message only
        if(!isRequest){

            SOAPMessage soapMsg = context.getMessage();

            if (soapMsg != null) {
               try {

                   java.util.Iterator iterator = soapMsg.getSOAPBody().getChildElements();
                   while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                     SOAPBodyElement bodyElement = (SOAPBodyElement) iterator.next();
                     String val = bodyElement.getTextContent();
                     bodyElement.setTextContent(stripNonValidXMLCharacters(val));    
                     System.out.println("The Value is:" + val);
                   }


               } catch (SOAPException ex) {
                  LOGGER.error("Failed to get and set source", ex);
               }

            }

        }

        //continue other handler chain
        return true;
    }




     public static String stripNonValidXMLCharacters(String in) {
          StringBuffer out = new StringBuffer(); // Used to hold the output.
          char current; // Used to reference the current character.

          if (in == null || ("".equals(in))) return ""; // vacancy test.
          for (int i = 0; i < in.length(); i++) {
              current = in.charAt(i); // NOTE: No IndexOutOfBoundsException caught here; it should not happen.
              if ((current == 0x9) ||
                  (current == 0xA) ||
                  (current == 0xD) ||
                  ((current >= 0x20) && (current <= 0xD7FF)) ||
                  ((current >= 0xE000) && (current <= 0xFFFD)) ||
                  ((current >= 0x10000) && (current <= 0x10FFFF)))
                  out.append(current);
          }
          return out.toString();
      }   

    @Override
    public boolean handleFault(SOAPMessageContext context) {

        System.out.println("Server : handleFault()......");

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void close(MessageContext context) {
        System.out.println("Server : close()......");
    }

    @Override
    public Set<QName> getHeaders() {
        System.out.println("Server : getHeaders()......");
        return null;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is change the XML without parsing it, as you have already figured out. This is not necessarily an easy problem, but at least more generic.

Take your message as a bare String first:

```
ByteArray OutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
soapMsg.writeTo(out);
String messageAsString = new String(out.toByteArray());
```

And then just use `stripNonValidXMLCharacters` on the string, and use the result as input for `SOAPMessageContext::setMessage`, which in your case seems to be `context.setMessage(...)`.

Also take a look at these for prettier ways of adjusting invalid XML: [removing invalid XML characters from a string in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4237625/removing-invalid-xml-characters-from-a-string-in-java), and [Parsing malformed/incomplete/invalid XML files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6982027/parsing-malformed-incomplete-invalid-xml-files).