# How to parse XML file with "Opening and ending tag mismatch" in Java

Tags: java, xml, parsing, tags

I have and XML file with open Price tag. Is there a way to parse the file despite the error? How to skip product with error and continue parsing?

```
<Products>
      <Product Name="Gummi bears">
        <Price Currency="GBP">4.07</Price>
        <BestBefore Date="19-02-2014"/>
      </Product>
      <Product Name="Mounds">
        <Price Currency="AUD">5.64
        <BestBefore Date="08-04-2014"/>
      </Product>
      <Product Name="Vodka">
        <Price Currency="RUB">70</Price>
        <BestBefore Date="11-10-2014"/>
      </Product>
  </Products>
```

Comment: I haven't tried myself, but here is some interesting answer suggesting using [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/) http://stackoverflow.com/a/6982108/3364457

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the code. It's an implementation to what BrandonArp  has already mentioned.

There's a property that need to set to ignore fatal error - **continue-after-fatal-error**

```
http://apache.org/xml/features/continue-after-fatal-error 
true:   Attempt to continue parsing after a fatal error.  
false:  Stops parse on first fatal error.  
default:    false  
XMLUni Predefined Constant:     fgXercesContinueAfterFatalError  
note:   The behavior of the parser when this feature is set to true is undetermined! Therefore use this feature with extreme caution because the parser may get stuck in an infinite loop or worse.
```

More detail can be found [here](https://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/program-sax2-3.html)

> PriceReader class

```
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;

import org.xml.sax.XMLReader;

public class PriceReader {

    public static void main(String argv[]) {

        try {
        SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();

        XMLReader xmlReader = saxParser.getXMLReader();

        try {
            xmlReader.setFeature(
                            "http://apache.org/xml/features/continue-after-fatal-error",
                            true);
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            System.out.println("error in setting up parser feature");
        }

        xmlReader.setContentHandler(new PriceHandler());
        xmlReader.setErrorHandler(new MyErrorHandler());
        xmlReader.parse("bin\\com\\test\\stack\\overflow\\sax\\prices.xml");

    } catch (Throwable e) {
         System.out.println("Error -- " +e.getMessage());
    }

    }
}
```

> PriceHandler class

```
import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

public class PriceHandler extends DefaultHandler {

    public void startElement(String uri, String localName,
        String qName, Attributes attributes)
        throws SAXException {

    if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("Product")) {
        System.out.println("Product ::: "+ attributes.getValue("Name"));
    }
  }
}
```

> MyErrorHandler class

```
import org.xml.sax.ErrorHandler;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.SAXParseException;

public class MyErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {

    private String getParseExceptionInfo(SAXParseException spe) {
        String systemId = spe.getSystemId();

        if (systemId == null) {
            systemId = "null";
        }

        String info = "URI=" + systemId + " Line=" 
            + spe.getLineNumber() + ": " + spe.getMessage();

        return info;
    }

    public void warning(SAXParseException spe) throws SAXException {
        System.out.println("Warning: " + getParseExceptionInfo(spe));
    }

    public void error(SAXParseException spe) throws SAXException {
        String message = "Error: " + getParseExceptionInfo(spe);
        System.out.println(message);
    }

    public void fatalError(SAXParseException spe) throws SAXException {
        String message = "Fatal Error: " + getParseExceptionInfo(spe);
        System.out.println(message);
    }
}
```

> Output

```
 Product ::: Gummi bears
Product ::: Mounds
Fatal Error: URI=file:///C:/Developer/pachat/workspaces/eclipse-default/stack-overflow/bin/com/test/stack/overflow/sax/prices.xml Line=9: The element type "Price" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</Price>".
Fatal Error: URI=file:///C:/Developer/pachat/workspaces/eclipse-default/stack-overflow/bin/com/test/stack/overflow/sax/prices.xml Line=9: The end-tag for element type "Price" must end with a '>' delimiter.
Product ::: Vodka
Product ::: Rum
Product ::: Brezzer
Fatal Error: URI=file:///C:/Developer/pachat/workspaces/eclipse-default/stack-overflow/bin/com/test/stack/overflow/sax/prices.xml Line=21: The element type "Price" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</Price>".
Fatal Error: URI=file:///C:/Developer/pachat/workspaces/eclipse-default/stack-overflow/bin/com/test/stack/overflow/sax/prices.xml Line=21: The end-tag for element type "Price" must end with a '>' delimiter.
Product ::: Water
Fatal Error: URI=file:///C:/Developer/pachat/workspaces/eclipse-default/stack-overflow/bin/com/test/stack/overflow/sax/prices.xml Line=26: The end-tag for element type "Product" must end with a '>' delimiter.
Fatal Error: URI=file:///C:/Developer/pachat/workspaces/eclipse-default/stack-overflow/bin/com/test/stack/overflow/sax/prices.xml Line=26: XML document structures must start and end within the same entity.
Fatal Error: URI=file:///C:/Developer/pachat/workspaces/eclipse-default/stack-overflow/bin/com/test/stack/overflow/sax/prices.xml Line=26: Premature end of file.
 Error -- processing event: -1
```

Comment: It seems like parsing stops after the error and we don't get third product.

Comment: Let me try to reproduce

Comment: Ok. I was able to re-produce and fix the issue. I will edit my answer

Answer (score 3):

The general way to deal with errors like this is to use a streaming parser.  The one that comes to mind for Java is SAX.

When creating a Handler, you will be able to override/implement the [error](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/xml/sax/helpers/DefaultHandler.html#error(org.xml.sax.SAXParseException)) and [fatalError](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/xml/sax/helpers/DefaultHandler.html#fatalError(org.xml.sax.SAXParseException)) methods.  These will allow you to continue parsing, but that still leaves you to handle the actual errors.

Obviously there are many possible errors in an XML document and it'll only make sense to handle some of them.  Hopefully this will give you a place to start with a parser, though.